# count how many days of year belong to an interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

[myTable] has 2 date type columns: startD and endD, and also other columns types. I want to see if every day of year 2015 is contained inside the interval [startD,end]

```
declare @t table ( A date, B date )
    insert into @t (A,B)
    select distinct startD, endD
    from myTable


    declare @start date = '2015-01-01'
    while @start < '2016-01-01'
    begin
    select 
     case
        when  @start >= @t.A and @start <= @t.B
            then 1
            else 0
      end as it
    from @t 
    set @start = DateAdd(day,1,@start) 
    end
```

Also, another issue: let's say I want to count how many `1` and `0` values are in the `365` values. How can I achieve this considering the above code?

If I change `t` to `@t` I get `Must declare the scalar variable "@t".`

Comment: where did you see `The multi-part identifier could not be bound` error?

Comment: Where I added the comment lines

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I have a feeling just printing `0s` and `1s` isn't your goal.

Comment: I want to count how many 0 and 1 values based on the if condition

Comment: What is your *initial* problem that you try to solve using this loop-based approach?

Comment: @FlorinM. No, you don't want to count how many 0 and 1 values you have. I'm under the impression that you're trying to solve a problem you have in an incorrect way (incorrect algorithm). With this code you'd just how many dates are greater than each of the dates in your table.

Comment: [myTable] has 2 date type columns: startD and endD. I want to see every day of year 2015 if it is contained by the interval [startD,endD]

Comment: @FlorinM. Ok, then you don't have to itterate in that scenario.

Comment: @FlorinM. And you want the number of days from 2015 in the interval of each `startD - endD`?

Comment: Yes. I am a little confused, considering the fact that I thought I must declare a temporary table containing just startD and endD. [myTable] contains also other columns

Comment: @FlorinM. No, You don't have to. You're approaching this programatically, when you should actually be using a set-based approach. Let me show you what I think you mean.. (I'm writing an answer now)

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that is inserted into `@t` and what your *expected* results are for that sample data?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use

```
if @start >= t.A and @start <= t.B -- how can I reffer to t.A and t.B ?
```

try like this

```
select case when @start >= A and @start <=B then 1 else 0 end as result
from @t
```

and after that you can print all the result value one by one.

or,

> (hope)solution:(i'm not sure what you really want,not clear but hope this'll
>   help you)

```
declare @start date = '2015-01-01'
declare @end date = '2016-01-01'

     select case when (A>=@start and A<@end) and (b>=A and B<=@end) then 1 else 0 end as result
        from @t
```

> if it's not what are you looking for then you just need to change the
>   logic in `case` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can count days using [**`DATEDIFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT IIF(y.days >=0, y.days + 1, 0) AS numOfDays
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT IIF('20150101' > startD, '20150101', startD),
         IIF('20151231' < endD, '20151231', endD) ) AS x([from],[to])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(d, x.[from], x.[to])) AS y(days)
```

The above query counts the number of days of year 2015 contained inside the interval `[startD, end]` of your table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29cbc/4)

Comment: mytable can contain duplicates of startD/endD, e.g.: 2015-01-01 (startD) - 2015-02-01 (endD) and 2015-01-01 (startD) - 2015-02-02 (endD). Should I consider a distinct filter?

Comment: I used your code for my situation and the result was in 20k rows. Mytable contains 1750 rows.

Comment: @FlorinM. My query returns one row for each row of the original table. Can you setup an sqlfiddle demonstrating the issue that you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement:

> I want to see if every day of year 2015 is contained inside the
>   interval

You can do this with the help of a Tally Table:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3865/0)

```
--Prepare sample data
DECLARE @t TABLE(startD DATE, endD DATE)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('20150101', '20150125'),
('20150301', '20150313');

DECLARE @year INT = 2015
DECLARE @numberOfDays INT

SELECT @numberOfDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0), DATEADD(YEAR, @year + 1 - 1900, 0))

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@numberOfDays)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteAllDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT
        CAST(DATEADD(DAY, N-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, 0)) AS DATE)
    FROM Tally
)
SELECT
    [Date]           = d.dt,
    [Is_In_Interval] = CASE WHEN t.startD IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM CteAllDates d
LEFT JOIN @t t
    ON d.dt BETWEEN t.startD AND t.endD
```